# $\forall$ a,b $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying a < b, $\exists$ n $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ such that a + $\frac{1}{n}$ < b.

Tags: real-analysis

My aim is to negate the statement.

Attempt:

$\exists$ a,b $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying a $\geq$ b, $\forall$ $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $a + \frac{1}{n} \geq b$.

When I went to search for the answer in the solution manual, I found that the author had the following:

$\exists a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $a < b$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $a + \frac{1}{n} \geq b$.

I don’t understand why the author didn’t negate the condition that $a < b$. Is this an error, or do I have a misunderstanding?

Thanks!

Comment: The statement in the title is true. So your proposed negation of it has to be false. But it's not, is it?

Comment: A piece of advice on formatting math: when you use single `$` characters to do the formatting, generally you should put *all* math formulas (including the names of variables) between the `$` characters, and in each case if the symbols you are dealing with are parts of a larger formula, you should put the entire larger formula inside a single pair of `$` characters. For example, write `$a \geq b$` rather than `a $\geq$ b`. In some places you seem to have followed this advice already, but it's inconsistent; compare the way $a + \frac{1}{n} < b$ is written in the question body and in the title.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand. The word "satisfying" implies a property of the numbers that is independent of the statement itself, much like a number can be prime, or divisible by 4. Therefore negation will have  no effect on this; the set of numbers is still the same.

You can also think of it like this:

The original statement can be reduced to this:

$a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $a < b$ is equal to picking elements from the set $S = \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 |  a< b\}$ and therefore the original statement can be written: $\forall a,b \in S, \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, a+\frac{1}{n}< b$

Applying negation to each part of this statement, you get:
$\exists a,b \in S, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, a+\frac{1}{n} \geq b$

Hence the result.
Note that this negated statement is always false, a result of the Archemedian property of the Real numbers

Comment: Wow, thank you. I understand. I will be more aware for future problems that are similar. Thank you again!